# Display SVG in IPython notebook from a function

Tags: python, svg, jupyter-notebook

In IPython notebook, the following code displays the SVG below the cell:

```
from IPython.display import SVG
SVG(url='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg')
```

The following displays nothing:

```
from IPython.display import SVG
def show_svg():
    SVG(url='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg')
```

Is there a way to display an SVG from within a function (or a class)?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You need to `display` the SVG like

```py
from IPython.display import SVG, display
def show_svg():
    display(SVG(url='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg'))
```

You first example works as the SVG object returns itself an is subsequently displayed by the IPython display machinery. As you want to create your SVG object in a custom method, you need to take care of the displaying.
The `display` call is similar to the ordinary `print` statement, but can handle different representations like images, html, latex, etc. For details have a look at the [rich display documentation](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/ipython/ipython/blob/3.x/examples/IPython%20Kernel/Rich%20Output.ipynb).

Comment: The `display` reference is really useful as it allow you to write multiple images inside a loop (for example)

Answer (score 8):

Add `return` to your function :

```
from IPython.display import SVG
def show_svg():
    return SVG(url='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a4/Flag_of_the_United_States.svg')
```

Then call your functions as the last line in cell:

```
show_svg()
```

Comment: The "return SVG(...)" does not display the svg from inside a script when run by Jupyter notebook. But the `display` does the job

Comment: Just tried again. Works for me in Chrome 66.0.3359.139 on Mac, IPython 6.1 ,  and Jupyter 4.3.0.

Comment: Can you please try with Safari and give the outcome ?

Comment: Works in Safari as well.

Comment: Do you call your `show_svg()` function directly from Jupyter or do you call `show_svg()` from a script and then type `%run myScript.py` in Jupyter ?

Comment: All from a Notebook cell. No script.

Comment: Put your `show_svg` function definition in `dummy.py` (for example) and then run `%run dummy.py` in a Jupyter NB cell with Safari and give the outcome

Comment: This does not work because `%run` starts an external process and the return value of the function call does not end up in the notebook.

Comment: Yes. That was my point from the beginning ([see my 1st comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334385/display-svg-in-ipython-notebook-from-a-function/30334467?noredirect=1#comment88271783_30334467))