# SVG output not displayed when opening an IPython / Jupyter Notebook

Tags: svg, jupyter-notebook

I'm writing some IPython / Jupyter Notebooks which calculate and display a lot of SVG figures. As a minimal example, consider the following:

[image: Notebook this displayed SVG output]

Almost every time I reopen such notebooks (especially the big ones), their figures are replaced by a textual output:

[image]

Of course, I could recalculate them by running all cells. But it is quite long, and the data are actually present in the JSON `.ipynb` file:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "code",
   "execution_count": 1,
   "metadata": {
    "collapsed": false
   },
   "outputs": [
    {
     "data": {
      "image/svg+xml": [
       "<svg baseProfile=\"full\" height=\"200\" version=\"1.1\" width=\"300\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\">\n",
       "\n",
       "  <rect fill=\"red\" height=\"100%\" width=\"100%\"/>\n",
       "\n",
       "  <circle cx=\"150\" cy=\"100\" fill=\"green\" r=\"80\"/>\n",
       "\n",
       "  <text fill=\"white\" font-size=\"60\" text-anchor=\"middle\" x=\"150\" y=\"125\">SVG</text>\n",
       "\n",
       "</svg>"
      ],
      "text/plain": [
       "<IPython.core.display.SVG object>"
      ]
     },
     "execution_count": 1,
     "metadata": {},
     "output_type": "execute_result"
    }
   ],
   "source": [
    "from IPython.core.display import SVG\n",
    "SVG(url=\"https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/3075/svgdemo1.xml\")"
   ]
  }
 ],
 "metadata": {
  "kernelspec": {
   "display_name": "Python 2",
   "language": "python",
   "name": "python2"
  },
  "language_info": {
   "codemirror_mode": {
    "name": "ipython",
    "version": 2
   },
   "file_extension": ".py",
   "mimetype": "text/x-python",
   "name": "python",
   "nbconvert_exporter": "python",
   "pygments_lexer": "ipython2",
   "version": "2.7.10"
  }
 },
 "nbformat": 4,
 "nbformat_minor": 0
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Is this a known bug? Can you reproduce this behaviour on [the same notebook](https://gist.github.com/laowantong/8f77e85736b4a674597a)? How to ensure that the SVG outputs is correctly shown each time I reopen a notebook?

Configuration: Fresh Mac OS X 10.10.4 installation of the latest IPython Notebook Anaconda package, but without any subsequent manual updates (i.e., this is still IPython 3.2.0-py27_0).

Comment: I was able to reproduce a similar behaviour by *untrusting* the Notebook (i.e. make it disagree with its signature, e.g. by doubling a space somewhere in the .ipynb file). Do you change the file in some way before opening it again? Do you reopen it on the same system? You may also check if the signatures are correctly written on your system. See [this](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/notebook/security.html).

Comment: Thanks @Taar. Your suggestion solved my problem. I have just selected File / Trust for my notebook, and boom! Next time I open it, all the SVG are correctly displayed. If you transform your comment into an answer, I would gladly accept it.

Comment: executing *all* cells and saving afterwards should produce a trusted notebook, and you shouldn't have to trust it manually. On my Windows 7+IPython 3.2.0+Py 3.4 config, I certainly don't. Your comment seems to imply that you don't do anything special after saving (modifying the file, changing profile, etc), so you may have found a bug. Maybe you should try to pinpoint it (first check that the abnormal behaviour remains when you execute all cells before saving) and then submit it to the relevant team?

Comment: Sorry for not having mentioned it: I rarely execute all cells, but frequently _do_ modify the resulting file programmatically (e.g., adding section links, table of contents, etc.). Now I have added `ipython trust my_doc.ipynb` to my script. So, probably no bug, except from my side :)

Comment: This may help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334385/display-svg-in-ipython-notebook-from-a-function