# Can't display SVG pictures with IPython.HTML

Tags: python, html, svg

I Tried to plot out SVG images with IPython using this

```
from from IPython.display import HTML, display
if '.svg' in link: #img_data = bunch of tags


    display(HTML(img_data)))


    continue
  image = io.imread(link)
  ratio = image.shape[1]/image.shape[0]
  print(ratio)
  
  print(image.shape)
  resized = cv.cvtColor(image, cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  
  resized = cv.resize(resized,(int(HEIGHT_RESIZED*ratio),HEIGHT_RESIZED),interpolation = cv.INTER_AREA)
  
  cv2_imshow(resized)
```

but when It reaches SVG images
it shows this
[small picture icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTJoI.png)
instead of the SVG image

Comment: Don't you need to use display(SVG( per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30334385/display-svg-in-ipython-notebook-from-a-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display SVG images in IPython with:

```
from from IPython import display
svg = '<svg ...'  # Replace with your SVG content.
display.SVG(svg)
```